# Why don't bars in star wars allow droids?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, attack-of-the-clones

In A New Hope Luke is told by the bartender at Mos Eisley that C3P0's kind were not served there

In Attack of the Clones while Anakin is taking Padme into hiding, they go into a bar and this time a droid bartender tells R2D2 (I think) to get out of the bar

**Why is there such racism against droids in Star Wars bars?**

Comment: Also: [Why doesn't the Mos Eisley Cantina allow droids?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/43048/5184)

Comment: but what about the scene in attack of the clones?

Comment: DVK's answer doesn't mention the AoTC bartender specifically, but does talk about the galaxy-wide prejudices. James Sheridan also gives a general reason.

Comment: Prejudice left over from when the separatist droid armies were rampaging around the galaxy? In fairness, not letting droids in your bar makes sense, though; they take up a customer-size space and don't eat or drink...